# MySQL match against with another criteria search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a simple MySQL query that when I add another search criteria, however, it fails to search in a reasonable time over 9000 seconds. The second column (col2) is indexed so I'm not sure how to run this query faster? Col1 is set to FULL TEXT and works fast when ran without the second criteria. Any help on this would be great. Below is an example of the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
where
match(col1) against('word1') AND
col2 = 'word2' 
limit 500000
```

Comment: Which index does `EXPLAIN` say is being used?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will not access a table using both FULLTEXT indexes and conventional B-tree indexes.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html under [EXPLAIN Join Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types). This is also called *access type*.

When you EXPLAIN the query, each table reference will show one access type, which is the method it uses to read the table. For instance, by unique index, by non-unique index, by table-scan, etc.

`fulltext` is one of these access types.

As far as I know, each access type is mutually exclusive with other join types. So it will either do a fulltext search, without using any other index, or else it will use your index on the other column, in which case it will not use the fulltext index.

It might still be a better choice to use the non-fulltext index, if that helps to select a narrow subset of rows more effectively than the fulltext index.